# How to get the index of Parentheses inside Parentheses in a String using Java

Tags: java, regex, string, parentheses

I am giving input as a String s1= (RT)PO(Q(IT)); and want output as RTPO(QIT) as a String. If there is a parenthesis as a first character I want to remove that parentheses and its closing parentheses. Also, if there are 2 continuous parenthesis then remove the inside one. If I get indexes of these parentheses then I can remove them.

Can somebody help me with that? I am not good with Regex.

Comment: show us your effort that you have spend to achieve this

Comment: `I am not good with Regex` ... and regex isn't very good for this sort of problem.  In general, you would need to write a parser to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The following code answers to your first requirement i.e

**If there is a parenthesis as a first character I want to remove that parentheses and its closing parentheses.**

***You can improvise the code for the rest

- in the below program i have implemented arraylist like a parser works .***

package mypackage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BracketsModifier {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scn=new Scanner(System.in);     
    System.out.println("enter the sample string ");     
    String sampleString=scn.next();
    int leftBracketCounter=0;
    int rightBrackerCounter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<sampleString.length();i++)
    {

        if(sampleString.charAt(i)=='(')
        {
            leftBracketCounter++;
        }
        else
            if(sampleString.charAt(i)==')')
            {

                rightBrackerCounter++;
                // System.out.println("first braket encounterd @ loc "+i);
            }
    }


if(leftBracketCounter==rightBrackerCounter)
{
    System.out.println("balanced String entered");

}
else {
    System.out.println("not a valid input");

}

    ArrayList< String>alist=new ArrayList<>();  
    int last_bracket_loc=0;

    for(int i=0;i<sampleString.length();i++)
    {
        if(sampleString.charAt(i)=='(')

        {
            alist.add("(");         
            }

        else if (sampleString.charAt(i)==')') {     
            int alist_size=alist.size();
            alist.remove(alist_size-1);
            last_bracket_loc=i;

        }           
    }

String temp = sampleString.substring(1,last_bracket_loc);
System.out.println("finally the data remained is "+ temp);

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex is no use for this. You can use the `indexOf(char ch, int fromIndex):`; and `StringBuilder` also have a `deleteCharAt(int position)`. So you just have to save the indexes of all opening and closing parenthesis in an `ArrayList` and delete them after. The subtility is of course, when you get a `(`, then get the `)` after, and look for the next `(` only after the last `)` (using the `fromIndex` parameter) and using some counter to remember how much parenthesis deep you are.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var demo = "(RT)PO(Q(IT))";
var regex = /\((\w+)\)/g;
document.write(demo.replace(regex,"$1"));
```

Comment: In java,`demo.replaceAll("\\((\\w+)\\)","$1")`